# Owl identification. Winter in Haliburton, Ontario, Canada

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

Is this owl a 'Great Grey Owl' or 'Barred Owl'? I'm thinking a Great Grey because it was quite huge - about 1.5 to 2 feet tall.

[image: owl]

Comment: [Cross-posted on The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/28002/6144)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is a nice picture of a Barred Owl. The heavy well-separated streaks on the breast and eye color (dark vs. yellow) are both distinctly different from that of the Great Gray. The markings in the facial disk are also distinctive — e.g. the fine even lines in the Great Gray vs. the blurry, more disordered pattern in the Barred. (Also Great Gray Owls are even bigger: 60-80+ cm long vs. 40-50 cm for Barred Owls.)

An excellent resource for identifying North American birds is the Cornell Lab of Ornithology's [All about birds site](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Great_Gray_Owl/species-compare/60394891). That link is to their comparison between these two species.

Comment: I agree. *Strix varia* (barred owl) vs larger, greyer, *Strix nebulosa*

Comment: Cornell has a great phone app, too, btw, to identify birds by sound. Its recognition accuracy is impressive.